# How to render with Fields plugin in Grails

Tags: grails, plugins

My code:

HotelController:

```
def search() {
    def result = Hotel.list()
    render(template: "searchTable", model: [hotelList: result], plugin: "fields")
}
```

views directory:

[image]

templates directory:

[image]

Error message:

```
URI
/hotel/search
Class
org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException
Message
null
Caused by
Unable to load template for uri [/hotel/_searchTable]. Template not found.

Around line 24 of grails-app\controllers\com\pool\HotelController.groovy
24:        render(template: "searchTable", model: [hotelList: result], plugin: "fields")
```

Should not be like that because fields plugin searches templates in `/templates/_fields` directory

If I try to place `_searchTable.gsp` template in `/hotel` directory - render method renders it as usual `<g:render>` tag

`compile: org.gerails.plugins:fields` is in build.gradle of course

Comment: It looks like `_searchTable.gsp` is in `templates/_fields/`, not `templates/`.

Comment: "Should not be like that because fields plugin searches templates in /templates/fields directory" - Your screenshot indicates that the folder name is `_fields` not `fields`.  Is that misleading, or is the folder really called `_fields`?

Comment: Yep, it really is in `/templates/_fields/` directory, but it is completely normal (I have another file there which works as expected via `<f:table>` tag)

Comment: I understand that it is normal.  Your question says "...because fields plugin searches templates in /templates/fields directory" and I thought there might be confusion around the directory name.  I am sorry for the noise.